# VirtualBox/Vagrant Fully Remove Virtual Machine to Clear Hash Sum Mismatches, etc

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I'm running Mavericks, and using Vagrant with VirtualBox to spin up a Precise32 box. When I first started, I had issues with `apt-get update` on the box (hash sum mismatches, etc.); so after weeks of trying to fix it, I just reinstalled my OS and tried again--problem solved. Unfortunately, the problem has returned after several months; so I cannot use the box anymore.

I have tried reinstalling Vagrant and tried deleting everything I could find that was associated with the box and re-adding the box; but nothing seems to work. **I'm guessing that there has to be something that's being left over from the old box(es)** (registry? I don't even know..), but I can't figure out what it is and how to remove it.

Thoughts? I just want to start with a totally fresh box without having to reinstall my OS.

**Edit 1**: I'm still looking into this, but this may be resulting from an internet filter that I installed (k9)--see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116979/65575).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled across [this question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116641/how-do-you-fix-apt-get-update-hash-sum-mismatch/116979#116979), which explains that having [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) installed caused these issues; and I realized that it probably had some merit, since I had not installed K9 immediately after reinstalling my OS--hence the reason I had no issues for a while. So I believe the current workaround is to not run K9, which has its downsides, obviously. I installed [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) on my router for home network filtering instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks has left me in tears, over a similar issue.

I upgraded to Mavs using appstore and, it went fine for a couple of weeks.

I think that the problem occured after I upgraded to the latest Virtualbox (I know nothing of Vagrant, Precise32, and I don't want to).

There came an occasion when I couldn't  VBoxManage - restart. It shut down the VM but, would not and cannot restart the VM.

Right now, I'm trying to work out a way to brute force Mountain Lion to install over Mavericks. I'm completely out of other ideas, apart from to get a tattoo that reads, 'Don't upgrade, just because it's there - it will only cause you to cry in your beer'.